# Multiple rows to single cell space delimited values in pandas with group by

Tags: r, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data set similar to df1 here

```
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,1,2,2,2],
                      'value':[67,45,7,5,9]})

   id  value
   1     67
   1     45
   2      7
   2      5
   2      9
```

I want to bring bring it to this form. all the values corresponding to that id in one cell separated by spaces.

```
   id values
   1  67 45
   2  7 5 9
```

Here is my code

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df1['id'].unique())
df2.columns=['id']
df2['values']=np.nan

for i in df2['id']:
    s=''
    for k in df1[df1['id']==i]['value']:
        s=s+' '+str(k)
    df2.loc[df2['id']==i,'values']=s.lstrip()
print(df2)
```

Is there a more pythonic way of doing this. I have 70000 unique id's, each id may have number of values ranging from 1 to 20

I am using 
Anaconda python 3.5
pandas 0.20.1
numpy 1.12.1
windows 10

Also, How can we replicate the same in R

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert the 'value' column from int to string, then perform a [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on 'id' and [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) the [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) function:

```
# Convert 'value' column to string.
df1['value'] = df1['value'].astype(str)

# Perform a groupby and apply a string join.
df1 = df1.groupby('id')['value'].apply(' '.join).reset_index()
```

The resulting output:

```
   id  value
0   1  67 45
1   2  7 5 9
```

Comment: What how would you do it, if instead of one value column there would be another column that should be joined the same way as the value column. For example a string that explains what each value-number stands for.
`df1 = df1.groupby('id')['value','value_string'].apply(' '.join).reset_index()` does not work

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do it in R. It is the same approach

```
df = data.frame('id'=c(1,1,2,2,2),'value'=c(67,45,7,5,9))
aggregate(cbind(values=value)~id,
           data = df, 
           FUN = function(x){paste(x,collapse=' ')})
```